# php exec('ssh user@server "bash" ... ) to open a remote terminal to do stuff?

Tags: php, linux, bash, ssh, exec

I checked some pages here (e.g: [How can I use PHP to setup an interactive SSH session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104236/how-can-i-use-php-to-setup-an-interactive-ssh-session) ) php.net/ssh2 i know ..

but no where i found an answer about the problems opening a remote shell (eg: bash) to do stuff at the remote side, closing it an the php script go's on.

php `exec('ssh user@server "bash -i -l", $bufferList)` works but the output goes to the local buffer.

closing the remote connection and i can work with the output (after/post processing). hmm

But: i was tring to enter custom commands at the remote side. Expecting the php script goes ahead when closing the connection. How to? Or do i have to use something like php/ssh2 and manage all the remote calls and answer posibilities at the local script?

--edit--

currently: i copy a shell script to the target server, login over there and execute it then.

To reproduce:

`exec('ssh user@server "ls -al", $bufferList);`
-> shows the list of files from the remote server of 'user' $HOME path `print_r($bufferList);` -> local output, connection closed

`exec('ssh user@server "bash -i -l", $bufferList); ->` print_r($bufferList);` -> empty array, connection closed.
Expected: Command Prompt.

Something to do with tty, but i have not found an answer yet.

Comment: do you want to get the result of the exec to the website?

Comment: @MaxMuster nope: ssh bash|dash|sh|zsh just in cli mode